# C++ Expression tree traversal to change expression to NNF in place

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to transform an expression into negation normal form. For this, I have a binary expression tree using smart pointers. The problem is that removing double negations is not working when they occur in binary expressions although the function `removeDoubleNot()` is called at the right time. So e.g. ¬(A∨¬B) becomes ¬A∧¬¬B instead of ¬A∧B, but it works on ¬¬B alone. I assume the mistake is in `evaluate()` but I could not find it yet. Maybe the recursion is wrong?

```
// It is assumed that all Expressions are valid
std::shared_ptr<Expression> NNF::removeDoubleNot(std::shared_ptr<Not> expr) {
    // Left is a Not -> remove both Nots
    if (auto node = dynamic_cast<Not *>(expr->getLeft().get()))
        return node->getLeft();
    return expr;
}

std::shared_ptr<Expression> NNF::applyDeMorgan(std::shared_ptr<Not> expr) {
    // And
    if (auto node = dynamic_cast<And *>(expr->getLeft().get())) {
        auto newLeft = std::make_shared<Not>(node->getLeft());
        auto newRight = std::make_shared<Not>(node->getRight());
        return std::make_shared<Or>(newLeft, newRight);
    }
    // Or
    if (auto node = dynamic_cast<Or *>(expr->getLeft().get())) {
        auto newLeft = std::make_shared<Not>(node->getLeft());
        auto newRight = std::make_shared<Not>(node->getRight());
        return std::make_shared<And>(newLeft, newRight);
    }
    return expr;
}

std::shared_ptr<Expression> NNF::removeImplication(const std::shared_ptr<Implication> &expr) {
    auto newLeft = std::make_shared<Not>(expr->getLeft());
    auto newRight = expr->getRight();
    return std::make_shared<Or>(newLeft, newRight);
}

std::shared_ptr<Expression> NNF::moveNegationInwards(const std::shared_ptr<Not> &notExpr) {     
    expr = applyDeMorgan(node);
    if (auto node = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Not>(expr))
        expr = removeDoubleNot(node);
    return expr;
}

std::shared_ptr<Expression> NNF::evaluate(std::shared_ptr<Expression> expr) {
    if (expr == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    // Implication
    if(auto node = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Implication>(expr)){
        auto ret = removeImplication(node);
        evaluate(ret->getLeft());
        evaluate(ret->getRight());
        return ret;
    }
    // Other binary than implication
    if(auto node = dynamic_cast<Binary*>(expr.get())){
        evaluate(node->getLeft());
        evaluate(node->getRight());
        return expr;
    }
    // Not
    if(auto node = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Not>(expr)) {
        auto ret =  moveNegationInwards(node);
        evaluate(ret->getLeft());
        evaluate(ret->getRight());
        return ret;
    }
    return expr;
}
```

Comment: It seems, in `applyDeMorgan`, you should do `auto newLeft = removeDoubleNot(std::make_shared<Not>(node->getLeft()));`, and similarly for other calculations.

Comment: What @cigien says applies to *every* sub-expression you negate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `evaluate(ret->getLeft())` you are not using the return value, thus you never change your current child expressions.
So you need to change this to:

```
ret->setLeft(evaluate(ret->getLeft()));
```

The same goes for right.

You might want to consider using [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) to get compiler warnings on mistakes like these.